# Unable to compile third-party package for iOS using Kivy toolchain

Tags: ios, kivy

I am working on a small testing project and wanted to add [Robot Remoteserver](https://github.com/robotframework/PythonRemoteServer) onto an iOS device but can't get toolchain to build the package successfully. Here's the errors I get when I attempt to build this package:

```
copying build/lib/robotremoteserver.py -> /Users/usman/kivy/kivy-ios/build/robotremoteserver/i386/PythonRemoteServer-master/iosbuild/lib/python2.7/site-packages
byte-compiling /Users/usman/kivy/kivy-ios/build/robotremoteserver/i386/PythonRemoteServer-master/iosbuild/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robotremoteserver.py to robotremoteserver.pyc
writing byte-compilation script '/tmp/tmpM9XgVf.py'
/Users/usman/kivy/kivy-ios/dist/hostpython/bin/python -OO /tmp/tmpM9XgVf.py
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
removing /tmp/tmpM9XgVf.py
running install_egg_info
Removing /Users/usman/kivy/kivy-ios/build/robotremoteserver/i386/PythonRemoteServer-master/iosbuild/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robotremoteserver-devel-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /Users/usman/kivy/kivy-ios/build/robotremoteserver/i386/PythonRemoteServer-master/iosbuild/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robotremoteserver-devel-py2.7.egg-info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./toolchain.py", line 1224, in <module>
    ToolchainCL()
  File "./toolchain.py", line 1040, in __init__
getattr(self, args.command)()
  File "./toolchain.py", line 1064, in build
build_recipes(args.recipe, ctx)
  File "./toolchain.py", line 933, in build_recipes
recipe.execute()
  File "/Users/usman/kivy/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 556, in execute
self.build_all()
  File "/Users/usman/kivy/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 56, in _cache_execution
f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/usman/kivy/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 668, in build_all
self.install()
  File "/Users/usman/kivy/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 56, in _cache_execution
f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/usman/kivy/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 794, in install
self.install_python_package()
  File "/Users/usman/kivy/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 835, in install_python_package
dest_dir)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 171, in copytree
names = os.listdir(src)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/usman/kivy/kivy-ios/build/robotremoteserver/i386/PythonRemoteServer-master/iosbuild/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robotremoteserver'
```

For the line **Could not find platform dependent libraries**  I did set the PYTHONPATH but still had this error.

Since there's no template to follow for the build script, I viewed the build files for the packages kivy comes with and created one that contains the following

```
from toolchain import PythonRecipe

class RobotRemoteServer(PythonRecipe):
    version = "master"
    url = "https://github.com/robotframework/PythonRemoteServer/archive/{version}.zip"
    depends = ["python"]


recipe = RobotRemoteServer()
```

I have ensured Kivy and the packages it depends on are all installed correctly. I've also searched the web but can't quite figure out what the problem is. I'm using Xcode 6.4 and latest [kivy](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios) pull from git. I have been stuck on this for a few days and appreciate any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Kivy recipes follow the same format as those for [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android). [Here](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/) you have the related documentation.